# How to verify the presence of a file written to a RAID-1 device?

Tags: command-line, raid

I have a RAID-1 (mirrored) array set up on two identical devices, `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. My procedure is documented [here](http://raid.handcrafted.codes/). Say I have a test file written to `/dev/md0`, *Stuff.txt*, that contains evidence of a vast government-alien conspiracy (something I'd naturally want to hang on to). Is there a command-line way to verify the presence of this file on each of these two devices?